# Java: automatic closing of files in BufferdStreamReader to avoid FileNotFoundException (too many open files)

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I have a legacy Java code that has opened a file and read lines as in the following code snippet within a method:

```java
BufferedReader brdr = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filenm)));
while ((String line = brdr.readLine()) != null) {   
    // ...
}
```

The variable fiilenm is passed in the method whenever called.
In order to avoid  `java.io.FileNotFoundException: ... (Too many open files)`, should I use `brdr.close()` to be on safer side?

Comment: Prefer using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: You should always close resources you've used.

Comment: You *must* close everything you create that is  closeable. This is not optional, or just 'to be on the safe side'.

Answer (score 0):

Use try-with-resources.

Readers/InputStreams implement AutoCloseable interface, try-with-resources utilizes it. so it returned resources when your program escape from the try block.

```
try (BufferedReader brdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filenm)))) {
    while ((String line = brdr.readLine()) != null) {   
      . ..
    } 
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

reference : [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: "try-with-resources implements AutoCloseable" - This statement is very confusing. Readers/InputStreams implement AutoCloseable interface, try-with-resources utilizes it.

Comment: It returns resources when the `try` block is done actually, which is  probably considerably sooner than when the program is done.

Comment: @Amongalen I agree. I misunderstood about Autocloseable interface. I will edit my answer. thank you!

Comment: @user207421 yes, so it is the reason 'try-with-resources'. thank you for your comment